# How to get only the specific elements in item.item of ansible with_items

Tags: ansible

The below ansible play use the uri module to call api and register the results into a variable defined,since it is iteration through with_items every iteration the results are append to variable.

```
   - hosts: nrpe
       vars:
          check_command:
               "/ Disk Usage": "check_disk! -a '-w 20% -c 10% -p /'"
               "/boot Disk Usage": "check_disk! -a '-w 20% -c 10% -p /boot"
            - name: API call 1
           uri:
             url: http://X.X.X.X/nagiosxi/api/v1/config/import?apikey=Aswddrdededde567g667786678&pretty=1
             method: POST
             body: -d "host_name=nagios-automate&service_description={{ item.key }}&use=generic-service&force=1&check_command ={{ item.value }}&max_check_attempts =5&check_interval=5&retry_interval=1&check_period=xi_timeperiod_24x7&notification_interval=60&notification_period=xi_timeperiod_24x7&notifications_enabled=1&_xiwizard=nrpe&register=1&applyconfig=1"
           register:  "r"
           with_dict: "{{ check_command }}"
           #with_sequence: start=0
         - debug:
               var=r
         - debug:
               msg= "{{ item.item }}"
           with_items: "{{ r.results }}"


Output:
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'content_length': u'87', '_ansible_parsed': True, u'cookies': {}, u'x_powered_by': u'PHP/5.4.16', '_ansible_item_label': {'key': u'/ Disk Usage', 'value': u"check_disk! -a '-w 20% -c 10% -p /'"}, u'access_control_allow_methods': u'*', u'access_control_allow_orgin': u'*', 'failed': False, u'json': {u'success': u'Imported configuration data. Config imported but not yet applied.'}, u'invocation': {u'module_args': {u'directory_mode': None, u'force': False, u'remote_src': None, u'status_code': [200], u'body_format': u'raw', u'owner': None, u'follow': False, u'client_key': None, u'group': None, u'use_proxy': True, u'unsafe_writes': None, u'serole': None, u'content': None, u'setype': None, u'follow_redirects': u'safe', u'return_content': False, u'client_cert': None, u'body': u'-d "host_name=nagios-automate&service_description=/ Disk Usage&use=generic-service&force=1&check_command =check_disk! -a \'-w 20% -c 10% -p /\'&max_check_attempts =5&check_interval=5&retry_interval=1&check_period=xi_timeperiod_24x7&notification_interval=60&notification_period=xi_timeperiod_24x7&notifications_enabled=1&_xiwizard=nrpe&register=1&applyconfig=1"', u'timeout': 30, u'url_password': None, u'dest': None, u'selevel': None, u'force_basic_auth': False, u'removes': None, u'http_agent': u'ansible-httpget', u'regexp': None, u'src': None, u'url': u'http://X.X.X.X/nagiosxi/api/v1/config/import?apikey=ADer45f56g565y5756y5657u5656F&pretty=1', u'validate_certs': True, u'seuser': None, u'method': u'POST', u'creates': None, u'headers': {}, u'delimiter': None, u'mode': None, u'url_username': None, u'attributes': None, u'backup': None}}, u'status': 200, '_ansible_item_result': True, u'msg': u'OK (87 bytes)', u'content_type': u'application/json', u'date': u'Wed, 12 Sep 2018 06:26:25 GMT', '_ansible_no_log': False, u'url': u'http://X.X.X.X/nagiosxi/api/v1/config/import?apikey=ADer45f56g565y5756y5657u5656F&pretty=1', u'changed': False, u'server': u'Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16', 'item': {'key': u'/ Disk Usage', 'value': u"check_disk! -a '-w 20% -c 10% -p /'"}, u'connection': u'close', u'redirected': False, u'cookies_string': u'', '_ansible_ignore_errors': None}) => {
    "msg": ""
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'content_length': u'87', '_ansible_parsed': True, u'cookies': {}, u'x_powered_by': u'PHP/5.4.16', '_ansible_item_label': {'key': u'/boot Disk Usage', 'value': u"check_disk! -a '-w 20% -c 10% -p /boot"}, u'access_control_allow_methods': u'*', u'access_control_allow_orgin': u'*', 'failed': False, u'json': {u'success': u'Imported configuration data. Config imported but not yet applied.'}, u'invocation': {u'module_args': {u'directory_mode': None, u'force': False, u'remote_src': None, u'status_code': [200], u'body_format': u'raw', u'owner': None, u'follow': False, u'client_key': None, u'group': None, u'use_proxy': True, u'unsafe_writes': None, u'serole': None, u'content': None, u'setype': None, u'follow_redirects': u'safe', u'return_content': False, u'client_cert': None, u'body': u'-d "host_name=nagios-automate&service_description=/boot Disk Usage&use=generic-service&force=1&check_command =check_disk! -a \'-w 20% -c 10% -p /boot&max_check_attempts =5&check_interval=5&retry_interval=1&check_period=xi_timeperiod_24x7&notification_interval=60&notification_period=xi_timeperiod_24x7&notifications_enabled=1&_xiwizard=nrpe&register=1&applyconfig=1"', u'timeout': 30, u'url_password': None, u'dest': None, u'selevel': None, u'force_basic_auth': False, u'removes': None, u'http_agent': u'ansible-httpget', u'regexp': None, u'src': None, u'url': u'http://x.x.x.x/nagiosxi/api/v1/config/import?apikey=ADer45f56g565y5756y5657u5656F&pretty=1', u'validate_certs': True, u'seuser': None, u'method': u'POST', u'creates': None, u'headers': {}, u'delimiter': None, u'mode': None, u'url_username': None, u'attributes': None, u'backup': None}}, u'status': 200, '_ansible_item_result': True, u'msg': u'OK (87 bytes)', u'content_type': u'application/json', u'date': u'Wed, 12 Sep 2018 06:26:26 GMT', '_ansible_no_log': False, u'url': u'http://x.x.x.x/nagiosxi/api/v1/config/import?apikey=ADer45f56g565y5756y5657u5656F&pretty=1', u'changed': False, u'server': u'Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16', 'item': {'key': u'/boot Disk Usage', 'value': u"check_disk! -a '-w 20% -c 10% -p /boot"}, u'connection': u'close', u'redirected': False, u'cookies_string': u'', '_ansible_ignore_errors': None}) => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

Shown output is from last statement of debug in the play,Here i want to limit the elements  being display and only required is "json"

json': {u'success': u'Imported configuration data. Config imported but not yet applied.'}

i have tried

item.item[0].json
item.item.json

but nothing works and end up getting

```
{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: dict object has no element 0\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/ansible-role-nrpe-client/api-call.yml': line 45, column 8, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n           var=r\n     - debug:\n       ^ here\n"}
```

how to get the json field alone in debug output

Answer (score 0):

There is no `item` key under the `r.results`. You just need to refer to the `json` key:

```
 - debug:
     msg: "{{ item.json }}"
   loop: "{{ r.results }}"
```

Comment: it is display whole result element

Comment: Yes, that's how `debug` module works. It displays the whole item **and** the value specified in `msg`. If you want to avoid that, there were plenty of questions on SO, please search.

Comment: item.json also returns whole result ,but want to limit only the element called json in the result

Comment: Please include that requirement in the question, so I can close the question as a duplicate. Right now the question is different and this is the answer.

Comment: item.json  not giving the expected result , as a work around would be

Comment: - debug:
           msg= "{{ item }}"
       with_dict: "{{ r.results }}"
       when: item.key == "json"